# Integrity constraint violation when trying to move Magento from Production to Local environment

Tags: database

**The problem**

I can't access the store front but I can enter the backend.

**What I want to achieve and what I did**

I installed WAMP and wanted to create a local environment which has a copy of the Magento shop on the Production environment.

I have followed these steps:

1. Backuped files
2. Created a database dump of the production server
3. Moved every file from "public_html"  to the local webserver
4. Created the database and imported the database dump on the local MySQL Server.
5. Made sure if I had every permission needed.
6. Updated the database-settings in app/etc/local.xml
7. Update the URLs in core_config_data:
8. Checked the .htaccess file.
9. Emptied the var/cache, var/session, var/report, var/log.
10. Logged in the backend. Reindexed  the data.

Now I have the following problem. 
I can log in to the backend. But when I try to get the store front then I get an error message: "There has been an error processing your request". So I went to "var/report" and red the error log number.

It said `"a:5:{i:0;s:96:"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '275374' for key 'PRIMARY'";i:1;s:2648:"#0 D:\wamp\www\lib\Varien\Db\Statement\Pdo\Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)".`

What does this mean? And why can I log into the backend but the storefront isn't displayed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868106/magento-sqlstate23000-integrity-constraint-violation-1062-duplicate-entry-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to execute this:

```
 TRUNCATE dataflow_batch_export ;
 TRUNCATE dataflow_batch_import ;
 TRUNCATE log_customer ;
 TRUNCATE log_quote ;
 TRUNCATE log_summary ;
 TRUNCATE log_summary_type ;
 TRUNCATE log_url ;
 TRUNCATE log_url_info ;
 TRUNCATE log_visitor ;
 TRUNCATE log_visitor_info ;
 TRUNCATE log_visitor_online ;
 TRUNCATE report_event ;
```